# Is it safe to access global variables in other thread after exit called?

Tags: c++, multithreading, global-variables, exit

I am analysing a dump one of the stack shows exit has been called

```
#0  0x00007fe2beac80a4 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fe2beac3444 in _L_lock_1087 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00007fe2beac32b6 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007fe2bece5325 in _dl_fini () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007fe2bd73a5e5 in __run_exit_handlers () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007fe2bd73a635 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

At the same time dump is in another thread when is trying to access global variable. So is it safe to access global variable in another thread after exit has been called? Would the global variable be destroyed "any time" after exit called?

Comment: It's not a particularly good idea to call [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) while you still have multiple threads running.  The POSIX specification for `exit()` refers to
[`_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html) and one of the consequences of a process calling `_exit` is that threads are terminated without calling their cleanup handlers, etc.  (_Threads terminated by a call to `_Exit()` or `_exit()` shall not invoke their cancellation cleanup handlers or per-thread data destructors._)

Comment: I haven't found direct advice against terminating a process while multiple threads are active, but messing around with global variables etc while another thread is killing the entire process is bound to be fraught, fragile, probably indeterminate, and generally a Bad Idea™.

Comment: Well, not really, not an any non-trivial multitasking OS.  Windows, linux etc. stop all threads in a process before deallocating any memory, global or not.  Stopping all threads in a busy process except one can be very difficult in a complex app. It means more code, (ie. more bugs), that needs developing, writing, testing etc. that adds nothing to the performance of the app while it is running.  The OS is MUCH better at stopping threads than user code because it has better tools and can stop any thread running on any core at any time - something that user code has problems with.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it safe to access global variable in another thread after exit
>   has been called?

On any non-trivial OS, yes. It's even safe to access local/automatic storage vars in other threads after exit has been called. Windows/linux etc. designers did think of this issue at design-time and so developed their process-termination sequence so that ALL threads in a process are stopped before any memory is released.  Process threads that are not in the running state have their state changed so that they can never be run again.  Process threads running on a different core than the thread that called 'exit' have their execution forcibly removed by means of a hardware interrupt to the core/s running them.  Only when ALL threads are stopped are resources like memory deallocated and released for re-use by other processes.

> Would the global variable be destroyed "any time" after exit called?

Yes.  The memory-segment hosting the global will be released by the OS at some time after exit is called.  This does not matter, however, since none of the process threads will be running at that time, whenever it is.

Note that all `exit()` calls are created equal:)  Some will run static dtors etc. before calling the OS to terminate the process and this can indeed cause problems with threads that call them that may be still running, resulting in possible UB/segfaults.  This becomes more likely with non-POD classes with non-trivial dtors.

If this is found to be an actual issue, either use an exit call that does not run the static dtors, (this may, or may not, matter, depending on what the dtor does, or needs to do), or avoid the issue by not using static globals, (not a bad plan anyway), or, as a last resort, go through the miserable, and usually avoidable, exercise of trying to cooperatively terminate the offending threads in user space before calling `exit()`.

Comment: But i found that one of my global variable destructor has been called..how is it possible? OS: SUSE10